Using React Navigate without a navigator
For context, my main App.tsx hosts a tab navigator which can route to the 'Groups' component, part of which is shown in the code block. I am attempting to navigate to a component that should be available from anywhere, 'Settings', via navigation.navigate.
I'm trying to avoid the use of a navigator because it interferes with the interface and there's no way to completely disable the visual elements of one, as far as I can tell. But without it, I get the following error: "The action navigate with payload {"name": Settings"} was not handled by any navigator".
Is there a way to navigate to a component without the use of a navigator? Or at the very least, a way to hide the navigator element in the interface so that navigation can be done through different React elements (in this case, the appbar)?
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View> 
        <Appbar.Header style={{backgroundColor: '#55a'}}>
            <Appbar.Content title="Groups" titleStyle={{color: '#fff'}}/>
            <PaperMenu
              visible={newMenuVisible}
              onDismiss={closeNewMenu}
              anchor={
              <Appbar.Action 
                color='white' 
                icon="plus-outline" 
                onPress={() => openNewMenu}
                />
              }>
              <PaperMenu.Item title="Group" />
            </PaperMenu>

            {/* Settings menu */}
            <PaperMenu
            visible={mainMenuVisible}
            onDismiss={() => setMainMenuVisible(false)}
            anchor={
              <Appbar.Action 
              color='white' 
              icon="dots-vertical" 
              onPress={() => setMainMenuVisible(true)}/>
            }>
            <PaperMenu.Item 
              title="Settings" 
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}/>
          </PaperMenu>
          </Appbar.Header> 
      </View>

I've tried implementing a Stack Navigator, which I thought would be invisible because there was nothing in it, but it still moves other elements around regardless.
